# Creating a new CE

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm a typo3 newbie, which is why im wondering how I can create a new custom content element. The content element should include a title/header, a subtitle/subheader, body text and **one** image. Clients shouldn't be able to add more than one image for each custom CE.

I'm trying to get the following render for the CE in the final html code.

```
<section class="tile">
<div class="img"></div> <!-- The image should be set as a background-image in css. -->
<div class="desc">
    <h1>Title</h1> <!-- Header -->
    <h2>Subtitle</h2> <!-- SubHeader -->
    <p> <!-- body text-->
        Body Text
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For create your own custom elements. Follow below link docs.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html

In this docs explain in details of How to create own custom content elements.

Answer (score 0):

A very comfortable way of adding custom CEs is to use the extension `mask`. It provides a kind of wizard with which you can add new CEs.